# Как можно расположить структуру данных по определенному адресу?

Tags: c

Есть у меня структура вида
typedef struct {
Int a;
Float b;
}
Как можно расположить её в определённом месте в памяти. Думаю для этого нужно использовать атрибуты.

Comment: ОСь пишите ? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем виде - создать указатель, присвоить ему нужный адрес, и потом заполнять структуру. Можно сделать атрибутами, но это уже зависит от среды разработки и компилятора и описано в документации
Вот такой код работает на атмеге, только что проверил:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t a;
    uint16_t arr[128];
} structure;


int main(void)
{
    structure * p;
    p = 0x71;
    p->a = 0x56;
    p->arr[6] = 0x11;
```

Массив окажется по адресу 0x71 в оперативной памяти